# Xamarin.Forms - AOT compile not working (for Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[This is the repository](https://github.com/FetFrumos/ApkSignerIssue) that demonstrates this issue.
This is simple standard project with one page. I created the archive for publishing (release mode).
If I use the "AOT compile" option, I get the error:

> "Apk failed to install Error:could not parse error string"

If I disable this option, then the APK works.

To use my test project, update the option `AndroidSigningKeyStore` in ApkSignerIssue.Android.csproj to point to file `test.keystore` in the folder `test`.

I'm on Windows 10 and I'm using Android Api 26. If I try Api 25, it does not work. I've tried using VS 15.5.7 and 15.8.0(preview) with "AOT compile" and neither of those work.

Without this option, XF+Android can not be used; the first load of the app will take 8-10 seconds.

It worked earlier, but now I can not build a package to release an update to my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade to 15.5.7 working for me now.

I do not know why this did not work right away, maybe I rebooted the computer. but now it works.

That's good - I was able to release an update my app.
And this is very sad - this is my fourth Downgrade in three months(starting from 15.6).
Archiving the package does not work normally three months, three months, Karl!

I lost a lot of time.